# Stop Terminal Server Grace Period

Tags: terminal, terminal-services

A remote desktop should be accessed simultaneously around 5 members. For that i had tried with 120 Days grace period of Terminal Server. After the grace period, i cant able to take the remote desktop. After that i have logged in directly and deleted the Grace Period Key from registry. After rebooting the server, it shows again 120 days grace period.

How to uninstall this. By default 2 users can use the remote desktop. That is enough for me. I have checked the services as well as administrative tools. I dint found any thing related to terminal server.

I have attached the warning message.

[image]

Comment: Still, i cant find any solution for my above problem. Any body faced this issue...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless, we get a licence this problem wont be solved.

But, by default the grace period will be 120. That can be renewed by doing the below process.

1. Delete the REG_BINARY in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\RCM\GracePeriod
2. In GracePeriod, leave the Default as it is.
3. Reboot the machine.

I have got this solution from the below mentioned URL and it worked out.

http://www.360ict.nl/blog/no-remote-desktop-licence-server-availible-on-rd-session-host-server-2012/

Every 119 days we need to delete the key. So that we will get another 120 grace period.

Comment: Will KMS licensed Windows server would work, to get rid of Grace period ? @robinhood

Answer (score 0):

uninstall the RDP Feature. 2 Users are always allowed to RDP into a Server and you will not need to rearm the RDP Feature

Comment: Perhaps you could explain _how_ to uninstall it. It would improve the quality of your answer.

Comment: It is a bit difficult to provide an exact how-to as it differs on different Windows-OS. Assuming W2008 here is an article which describe basically how-to uninstall Roles and Features:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732257(v=ws.11).aspx

Answer (score 0):

*IF* you only need the two users, run your RDP session as administrator. Then you'll be able to log in and won't have to worry about the grace period. If you run from the Run box - "mstsc /v:[SERVER NAME] /f /admin". The "/f" parameter gives you full screen.